# react-hook-form using useFieldArray with multiple array

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I coding something like this:

```
const [state1, setState1] = useState<any[]>([]);
const [state2, setState2] = useState<any[]>([]);
const {control, setValue, watch, handleSubmit, reset} = useForm({
    mode: 'onSubmit',
    defaultValues: {
        defaultValues1: useMemo(() => [...state1], [state1]),
        defaultValues2: useMemo(() => [...state2], [state2])
      },
  });
const { fields: defaultValues1,
    remove: removeDefaultValues1,
    append: appendDefaultValues1} = useFieldArray({ control, name: "requestBody.defaultValues1" });

  const { fields: defaultValues2,
    remove: removeDefaultValues2,
    append: appendDefaultValues2 } = useFieldArray({ control, name: "requestBody.defaultValues2" });

useEffect(() => {
    const tempData1: any[] = [];
    data.branch1.map(item => {
      tempData1.push(item);
    })
    setState1(tempData1)
}, [setState1])

useEffect(() => {
    const tempData2: any[] = [];
    data.branch2.map(item => {
      tempData2.push(item);
    })
    setState2(tempData2)
}, [setState2])
```

But when I log: watch('defaulValue1') => [] and watch('defaulValue1') => []
Where I was wrong about syntax of react-hook-form.